# What happens to remote process hosting service after service is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-memory

I have service bound to app context, this service runs in a separate process (lets say #service_process).
I simulate app crash by throwing uncaught exception and app's main process(#main_proccess) stops, obviously killing and GCing components, including main app context.
Service is also unbound(disconnected) and destroyed(I have Service#onDestroy() called).

However, the #service_process remains alive, according to `$ adb shell ps | grep com.my_app` even after #main process is dead.

Can anyone explain the reasons for such behavior ?
How is it possible to avoid having 'dangling' #service_process ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, service processes is not much different from foreground ones. As described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html)

> An unusual and fundamental feature of Android is that an application
>   process's lifetime is not directly controlled by the application
>   itself. Instead, it is determined by the system through a combination
>   of the parts of the application that the system knows are running, how
>   important these things are to the user, and how much overall memory is
>   available in the system.

And this one:

> service process ... so the system will always keep such processes
>   running unless there is not enough memory to retain all foreground and
>   visible process.

Comment: Thanks, but as I described I bind to the service and don't start it, so I do not have `3. Service process`. May be I have what is referred to by `5. empty process`

Comment: I don't think so, because it doesn't matter if You bind it or call startService() (both ways process will start, but in bind case it will have binding setuped). It actually matters just for call of onDestroy for Your service, but not for process lifetime as per my understanding and I'm not able to find any info about binding / process lifetime relation.